# Setting variable at perl invocation

Tags: perl

I'm trying to set variable for the perl via the `-s` and `-var=value`.

```
perl -s -E 'say $xx if $xx' -xx=abc
```

prints

```
No Perl script found in input
```

It probably didn't works together with the `-E` or i'm doing something wrong. (the `perlrun` doesn't mentions about the wrong combination of `-E` and `-s`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a -- to end the built-in perl options and start your user supplied ones:

```
perl -s -E 'say $xx if $xx' -- -xx=abc
```

As is, perl thinks you are using its -x switch.

(That said, -s is a really lousy thing to try to use these days; use Getopt::Long.)

Comment: thanx - and yes, the perlrun mentions the `--` but didnt understand how it means it. ;)

Comment: it doesn't do anything besides separate between perl switches and program name/arguments.

Comment: i like the `-s` idea for the one-liners.

Comment: I get this error that goes away when I use double quotes (I replaced say with print since I don't have a say function...): Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.

Comment: @user3885927: exactly what are you doing?  what perl version?  what OS?

Comment: @kobame: how about instead: `XX=ABC perl -E 'say $ENV{XX} if $ENV{XX}'`

Comment: perl v5.10.0 and the command line I executed is: perl -s -E 'print $xx if $xx' -- -xx=abc

Comment: Yes, ENV variables are nice idea - thanx ;)

Comment: @user3885927 but you said you used double quotes??

Comment: It works when I use double quotes and gives the error when I use single quotes that you suggested in your answer.

Comment: @user3885927: ah, that would be because you use a command shell that doesn't do the right thing with single quotes - nothing to do with perl. (note my question that you didn't answer)

Comment: @user3885927 yup.  that doesn't treat single quotes specially, so perl's -E switch gets given `'say` as the program to run.  (double quotes don't work universally either; with a unix-like shell, they will interpolate $xx as a shell variable, stripping it out if there is none, leaving a program of `print  if `.)